# Accumulo Overview console not reachable outside of VirtualBox VM

Tags: virtualbox, accumulo

I am running Accumulo 1.5 in an Ubuntu 12.04 VirtualBox VM. I have set the accumulo-site.xml instance.zookeeper.host file to the VM's IP address, and I can connect to accumulo and run queries from a remote client machine. From the client machine, I can also use a browser to see the hadoop NameNode, browse the filesystem, etc. But I cannot connect to the Accumulo Overview page (port 50095) from anywhere else than directly from the Accumulo VM. There is no firewall between the VM and the client, and besides the Accumulo Overview page not being reachable, everything else seems to work fine.

Is there a config setting that I need to change to allow outside access to the Accumulo Overview console?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the Accumulo monitor to bind to all network interfaces by manually applying this patch:
https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=accumulo.git;a=commit;h=7655de68

In `conf/accumulo-env.sh` add:

```
# Should the monitor bind to all network interfaces -- default: false
export ACCUMULO_MONITOR_BIND_ALL="true"
```

In `bin/config.sh` add:

```
# ACCUMULO-1985 provide a way to use the scripts and still bind to all network interfaces
export ACCUMULO_MONITOR_BIND_ALL=${ACCUMULO_MONITOR_BIND_ALL:-"false"}
```

And modify `bin/start-server.sh` to match:

```
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do # resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
   bin="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
   SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
   [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$bin/$SOURCE" # if $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
done
bin="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
# Stop: Resolve Script Directory

. "$bin"/config.sh

HOST="$1"
host "$1" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   LOGHOST="$1"
else
   LOGHOST=$(host "$1" | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)
fi
ADDRESS="$1"
SERVICE="$2"
LONGNAME="$3"
if [ -z "$LONGNAME" ]; then
   LONGNAME="$2"
fi
SLAVES=$( wc -l < ${ACCUMULO_HOME}/conf/slaves )

IFCONFIG=/sbin/ifconfig
if [ ! -x $IFCONFIG ]; then
   IFCONFIG='/bin/netstat -ie'
fi

# ACCUMULO-1985 Allow monitor to bind on all interfaces
if [ ${SERVICE} == "monitor" -a ${ACCUMULO_MONITOR_BIND_ALL} == "true" ]; then
    ADDRESS="0.0.0.0"
fi

ip=$($IFCONFIG 2>/dev/null| grep inet[^6] | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/addr://' | grep -v 0.0.0.0 | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | head -n 1)
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
   ip=$(python -c 'import socket as s; print s.gethostbyname(s.getfqdn())')
fi

if [ "$HOST" = "localhost" -o "$HOST" = "`hostname`" -o "$HOST" = "$ip" ]; then
   PID=$(ps -ef | egrep ${ACCUMULO_HOME}/.*/accumulo.*.jar | grep "Main $SERVICE" | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'} | head -1)
else
   PID=$($SSH $HOST ps -ef | egrep ${ACCUMULO_HOME}/.*/accumulo.*.jar | grep "Main $SERVICE" | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'} | head -1)
fi

if [ -z $PID ]; then
   echo "Starting $LONGNAME on $HOST"
   if [ "$HOST" = "localhost" -o "$HOST" = "`hostname`" -o "$HOST" = "$ip" ]; then
      #${bin}/accumulo ${SERVICE} --address $1 >${ACCUMULO_LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE}_${LOGHOST}.out 2>${ACCUMULO_LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE}_${LOGHOST}.err & 
      ${bin}/accumulo ${SERVICE} --address ${ADDRESS} >${ACCUMULO_LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE}_${LOGHOST}.out 2>${ACCUMULO_LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE}_${LOGHOST}.err & 
      MAX_FILES_OPEN=$(ulimit -n)
   else
      #$SSH $HOST "bash -c 'exec nohup ${bin}/accumulo ${SERVICE} --address $1 >${ACCUMULO_LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE}_${LOGHOST}.out 2>${ACCUMULO_LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE}_${LOGHOST}.err' &"
      $SSH $HOST "bash -c 'exec nohup ${bin}/accumulo ${SERVICE} --address ${ADDRESS} >${ACCUMULO_LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE}_${LOGHOST}.out 2>${ACCUMULO_LOG_DIR}/${SERVICE}_${LOGHOST}.err' &"
      MAX_FILES_OPEN=$($SSH $HOST "/usr/bin/env bash -c 'ulimit -n'") 
   fi

   if [ -n "$MAX_FILES_OPEN" ] && [ -n "$SLAVES" ] ; then
      if [ "$SLAVES" -gt 10 ] && [ "$MAX_FILES_OPEN" -lt 65536 ]; then
         echo "WARN : Max files open on $HOST is $MAX_FILES_OPEN, recommend 65536"
      fi
   fi
else
   echo "$HOST : $LONGNAME already running (${PID})"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the monitor is bound to the correct interface, and not the "localhost" loopback interface. You may have to edit the monitors file in Accumulo's configuration directory with the IP/hostname of the correct interface.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where/how to add this setting? I don't have a 'monitors' file, and there's nothing in the accumulo-site.xml from the examples.

Comment: You can create a monitors file in Accumulo's conf directory. It has the same format as the masters or slaves file. If one doesn't exist, it will fall back to the contents of the masters file.